# Express MongoDB, & Mongoose DELETE with findByIdAndRemove() then redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm currently trying to use a DELETE method however it seems like the res.redirect isn't triggering.

As you can see I am trying to delete a record in MongoDB using findByIdAndRemove():

```
  app.delete("/car", (req, res) => {
    Car.findByIdAndRemove(req.body.id, (err, car) => {
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  });
```

When I send a DELETE request through Postman with the id the server doesn't respond and appears to hang.

Any idea why this might be happening? I'd like it to delete the record with the id past and then redirect to the homepage.

Thanks

Comment: Can you console.log just before the redirect? Just to make sure you db action completes ok?

Comment: It can happen if you don't have a connection to the database. Make sure mongod is running and that the connection is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle the error returned by mongodb, if the query throw error or `req.body.id` is `undefined` the page will hangs because you didn't terminate the request/response cycle by [sending a response](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#response-methods) to clients, here is an example:

```
app.delete("/car", (req, res) => {

    Car.findByIdAndRemove(req.body.id, (err, car) => {

        // check if query error
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.json({ success: false });
        }

        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:-

```
    const id=req.body.id.toString().trim();

    Car.findByIdAndRemove(id,function(err){
    if(!err){
    res.redirect("/");
    };
    });
```